# how can i get all records of filter id in django

Tags: django

> the code i've done showing only one first save record in database
>
> > whether the id data consists more than once.

```
class Lab(models.Model):
    address=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    age=models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=11)

    sex_category=(('Male','Male'),('Female','Female'),('Others','Others'),)
    sex=models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=sex_category,default="Male")
    contact=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photo/',blank=True,null=True)

    user  = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile)

    # patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient)

    def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):
        return self.is_lab

    def has_module_perms(self,app_Label):
        return self.is_lab

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name

class Lab_Test(models.Model):
    test_name=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=False)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=False,choices=(('Done','Done'),('Pending','Pending')),
                            default='Pending')
    result=models.TextField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    test_date=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    lab=models.ForeignKey(Lab)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient.name

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def lab_check_pats_list(request):
    if request.user.is_lab:
        lab=UserProfile.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        labs=Lab.objects.get(user=lab.id)

        labt=Lab_Test.objects.filter(lab_id=labs.id)
        print(labt)


        pt = []
        for x in labt:
            pt.append(x.patient_id)
        pts= Patient.objects.filter(id__in=pt)

        context={
        'ab':zip(pts,labt)
        }

        print(pts)
        return render(request,'lab_check_pats_list.html',context)
```

> > i want to grab  all the record of the filter id but it is only showing
> >     once [id 1,2,3,4 data contains more than one but it is showing only once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcwIm.png)

[here for same user id is different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38md9.png)

Comment: use `filter` instead of 'get'

Comment: Show Lab and Lab_Test models

Comment: no it doesn't work

Comment: can you show UserProfile model code

Comment: id is unique for each model may be you are using ambiguous names

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
context={
    'ab':zip(pts,labt)
}
```

As you are ziping the result, its mapping first `Lab` to first `Patient` that is why you are seeing one result. I would suggest you to take a more django like approach. Like this:

First update the lab test like this:

```
class Lab_Test(models.Model):
    test_name=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=False)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=False,choices=(('Done','Done'),('Pending','Pending')),
                            default='Pending')
    result=models.TextField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    test_date=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, related_name="labtests")  # Updated here
    lab=models.ForeignKey(Lab)
```

Then change the view like this:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def lab_check_pats_list(request):
    if request.user.is_lab:
        lab=UserProfile.objects.get(id=request.user.id).lab # Because its a OneToOne relation
        lab_tests=Lab_Test.objects.filter(lab=lab)
        context={
            'lab_tests': lab_tests
        }

        return render(request,'lab_check_pats_list.html',context)
```

Now in template, you can access patient value like this:

```
{% for lab_test in lab_tests %}

    {{ lab_test.patient.name }}
    {{ lab_test.patient.contact }}
    {{ lab_test.id }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks ruddra ..it's working  but it it is possible to assign same id for same user in records

Comment: sorry, I did not get your question :( can you please elaborate?

Comment: the output of  { lab_check_pats_list},showing all records of same user but  the same user contains different id

Comment: can you share some screenshots of that? also can you share your template code as well? thanks